# Чи варто використовувати слово "виглядає" у значенні "має вигляд"?

Tags: синоніми

Звісно, слово [*виглядає*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyghljadaty) є у словнику, але основні значення *висуваючись дивитися*, *виднітися*, *чекати*. Значення **мати певний зовнішній вигляд** наче теж є, але є і сумніви у легітимності його використання.

Чи варто використовувати слово *виглядає* у значенні *"має вигляд"*? Яким словом його можна замінити?

Контекст

- Ти виглядаєш засмученим і розбитим
- Ось так ця сторінка/блок виглядає зараз
- Виглядає воно не дуже файно, але ми ще попрацюємо над дизайном
- — Але ж бо ти файно виглядаєш! (**Іван Франко**, IV, 1950, 9)

До речі, проблем з іменником [*вигляд*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyghljad) ніяких не маю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Олександр Пономарів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), доктор філологічних наук, професор, [пише](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-39217093)

> І відповідь на запитання письменника Андрія Горбунова. Він хоче
>   довести закономірність уживання слова **виглядати** в значенні російського
>   **выглядеть**.
>
> Для цього наводить приклади з польської, білоруської, англійської та
>   інших мов. Скаржиться, що редактор у всіх випадках повиправляв йому
>   **виглядати** в значенні російського **выглядеть** на **мати вигляд**.
>
> Тут треба сказати, що редактор передав куті меду. Замість **гарно
>   виглядаєш** справді треба писати **маєш гарний вигляд**.
>
> Замість *Іван **виглядав** стурбовано* потрібно *Іван **видавався** стурбованим*.
>
> **Виглядає** дивно - **видається** дивним.
>
> Печені яблука, политі медком, **виглядають** апетитно можна замінити на
>   апетитні **на вигляд**.
>
> Отже, основне значення дієслова **виглядати** - це дивитися кудись, крізь
>   щось, видніти, вдивлятися кудись. "*Марно, брате, не вигляне чорнобрива
>   з хати*" (Тарас Шевченко). "*Біля воріт давно вже виглядала синів
>   стривожена мати*" (Михайло Стельмах).
>
> Найголовніший аргумент - відсутність значення "**мати вигляд**" у дієслова
>   **виглядати** у Словнику за редакцією Бориса Грінченка, який є основним
>   мірилом українськості питомих українських слів.
>
> Наявність такого значення в окремих авторів не є достатньою підставою
>   для поширення в літературній мові. Від поширеності помилка не перестає
>   бути помилкою.

Схоже пояснення [знаходимо](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SY1nMW9w4A8) у експрес-уроках української мови [Олександра Авраменка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) і у його книгах.

Answer (score 4):

[За поданим посиланням є третє значення, яке описує даний випадок](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyghljadaty)

> ВИГЛЯДАТИ 3, аю, аєш, недок. Мати певний зовнішній вигляд. Виглядала
> вона [Одарка] старою бабусею, а їй усього було літ за тридцять...
> (Панас Мирний, I, 1954, 50); Хатинка виглядала досить привітно (Микола
> Трублаїні, II, 1955, 202); Прапороносець — стрункий, жилавий, років
> під тридцять — був по-військовому підтягнутий, виглядав молодецьки
> (Юрій Смолич, Мир.., 1958, 51).

Тому, це цілком нормально використовувати дане дієслово у даному контексті