# Чи правильно вживати "п'яний вигляд"

Tags: вживання-слів

Цікавить, чи можна вживати словосполучення "у п'яному вигляді".  У [Словнику української мови. Академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/netverezyj) знаходимо, що слово "нетверезий" можна вживати зі словом "стан". З того, що мені відомо, то "нетверезий вигляд" - словосполучення некоректне. А як бути зі словосполученням "п'яний вигляд"?

Маємо ж навіть  [Статтю 178. Розпивання спиртних напоїв у громадських місцях і поява в громадських місцях у п’яному вигляді](http://yurist-online.com/ukr/uslugi/yuristam/kodeks/001/286.php)

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2815/

Answer (score 5):

У законодавстві справді є поняття ***"п'яний вигляд"*** - і воно відрізняється від поняття  ***"нетверезий стан"***.

[Ст. 178](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/80731-10#n1904) Кодексу України про адміністративні правопорушення передбачає відповідальність за *появу в громадських місцях **у п'яному вигляді**, що ображає людську гідність і громадську мораль*.

У наступній ([179](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/80731-10#n1912)) статті цього Кодексу йде мова про *перебування на роботі **в нетверезому стані***.

Також можна згадати і [ст. 180](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/80731-10#n1918) КУпАПу, назва якої - *Доведення неповнолітнього до **стану сп'яніння.***

Складається враження, що законодавець свідомо вживає у цих статтях різні поняття.

### Стан сп'яніння

Існує [Інструкція](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z1413-15), яка

> визначає процедуру проведення огляду водіїв транспортних засобів на *стан алкогольного, наркотичного чи іншого сп’яніння* або перебування під впливом лікарських препаратів, що знижують увагу та швидкість реакції (далі – **стан сп’яніння**)

Як бачимо, *стан сп’яніння* тут - широке поняття, яке серед іншого включає *стан алкогольного сп’яніння*.

До речі, в Інструкції перелічені такі ознаки **алкогольного сп’яніння**:

> запах алкоголю з порожнини рота;
>
> порушення координації рухів;
>
> порушення мови;
>
> виражене тремтіння пальців рук;
>
> різка зміна забарвлення шкірного покриву обличчя;
>
> поведінка, що не відповідає обстановці.

### Нетверезий стан

За [ст. 40](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/322-08#n231) Кодексу законів про працю України:

> Трудовий договір, укладений на невизначений строк, а також строковий трудовий договір 
>   до закінчення строку його чинності можуть бути розірвані власником або уповноваженим ним органом лише у випадках:
>   7) появи на роботі в **нетверезому стані**, у стані наркотичного або токсичного сп'яніння

З цієї норми вбачається, що нетверезий стан - це, власне, стан алкогольного сп'яніння (як ми вже побачили, сп'яніння буває не лише алкогольним).

### П'яний вигляд

Роз'яснення цього поняття можна знайти у журналі ["Держава і право"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=neUjAQAAIAAJ&q=%D0%BF%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%96+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96&dq=%D0%BF%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%96+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib_oPp7NzlAhWCmIsKHTfRBXgQ6AEIOTAC) за 2002 рік (випуск 18):

> ***П'яний вигляд*** - зовнішня ознака, яка є наслідком уживання алкогольних напоїв і проявляється у поведінці особи, її ставленні до громадського порядку, оточуючих, зовнішньому вигляді. Необхідно враховувати при цьому, що особа в п'яному вигляді перебуває в певному стані, або своїми діями, поведінкою ображає людську гідність та громадську мораль. Інколи цей стан супроводжують: непристойні висловлювання, жести, викрики, настирливе приставання до громадян та інше; брудний, мокрий, розстібнутий одяг, неохайний зовнішній вигляд, що викликає відразу; втрата орієнтації, порушення координації рухів, втрата можливості самостійно пересуватись; втрата почуття сорому.

Ось самі фрагменти з Google Books:

[image]
[image]

У цьому ж журналі застерігають від ототожнення нетверезого стану і п'яного вигляду:

[image]
[image]
[image]

[...]

[image]

Доступу до решти статті, де автор розвиває цю думку, у мене нема. Та з останнього фрагмента можна зрозуміти, що не кожен, хто вживав алкогольні напої, набуває *"п'яного вигляду".*

### Висновки

***Сп'яніння*** може бути алкогольним, наркотичним, токсичним.

***Нетверезий стан*** - це стан алкогольного сп'яніння.

Особа може перебувати у *нетверезому стані* (стані алкогольного сп'яніння), але при цьому не мати ***п'яного вигляду***, що ображає людську гідність і громадську мораль. Тобто поводитися більш-менш пристойно.

---

*Примітка:* у ст. 180 КУпАП, очевидно, йде мова про доведення неповнолітнього до стану сп'яніння у вузькому значенні слова (алкогольне сп'яніння). За *незаконне введення в організм неповнолітнього наркотичних засобів* чи *схиляння до вживання наркотичних засобів* передбачена значно суворіша відповідальність (статті [314](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2341-14#n2187), [315](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2341-14#n2194) Кримінального кодексу).